# Cell format for usage statements

Tags: usage-messages

The `myFunc::usage` statement is intended to be a simple summary of the symbol and its arguments. However, many users like myself opt out of using Workbench and prefer to maximize use of the Notebook interface. That means I often find myself wanting to put more than a line or two into a usage statement. Unfortunately, the normal Input cell wrap's the text too early and before reaching the page margin. In addition, the formatting of the result obtained from using the query `?myFunc` is indented and line wrapped oddly.

You can see the oddity if you play around with the Notebook WindowSize using this example:

```
myFunc::usage = "myFunc[a, b, c]\n 
computes the meaning of life as a function of age a (yrs), brains b \
(moles/m^3), and coffee consumption c (gallons).  ";
```

Can someone help me design a Cell format that is specific to `::usage?` The cell would have the following characteristics:

a) no indentation after carriage return
b) wrapping at the page margin in Working Screen Environment

The screenshot below should help:

[image]